# How to write htaccess to only allow access to my site via specific domain (referrer)

Tags: .htaccess, http, referrer

I'm trying to setup a .htccess file in order to only allow access to the Thank You page from a certain referral HTTP. Specifically, I'm using MailChimp which emails the user an email to confirm their registration. Once the user clicks "confirm", they are re-directed to the Thank You page. Currently, the user is being redirected to the 403 error page but instead they **should be allowed access.**

**Note:** The htaccess file is in its own thankyou folder, along with thankyou.html, so it only applies to that directory.

htaccess code:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://jackrabbit.us10.list-manage.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /403.html [L,R]
```

I'm guessing my http_referer link is wrong. `jackrabbit`is my domain and `jackrabbit.us10.list-manage.com/`is what MailChimp's staff told me to try. They said the full confirmation URL would be: `http://jackrabbit.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/confirm?u=13dafa22fd7323ca3009dd515&id=2234dadf3ba0&e=*%3CUNIQID%3C*` but since `CUNIQ` changes based on the user, I should try the shortened version.

Can anybody help?  I've tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mail1.mcsignup.com/.*$ [NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://jackrabbit.us10.list-manage.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://us10.list-manage.com/.*$ [NC]
```

and here is a screenshot of my email, showing the MailChimp confirmation button. Clicking this button should redirect me to my thank you page (let's call jackrabbit.net/thankyou/thankyou.html) But its' being blocked via htaccess.

[image]

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The confirm click has a link to mail chimp?

Comment: See in my screenshot, that orange button? That was generated by MailChimp and sent to my email. Once I click that button, it redirects me to my thankyou page, except that I'm being blocked currently by the htaccess file. I need to edit this file to allow access ONLY via this method (via MailChimp's confirm button).

Comment: Look at the soucre of the email or right click inspect element on the button to see the link. But it's possible a referer might not be sent or the URL changes after you click it. Open Dev tools in Chrome and check the network tab and see if you can watch it and then when you get to your page, click on your page in dev tools to see the referer it came from.